# How to enable shortdesc output on DITA markdownn with DITA open toolkit?

Tags: markdown, dita, dita-ot

I want to convert my markdown styled DITA content to HTML5 styled output with DITA OT 3.0.3.

I checked syntax page and I understand it as 1st paragraph will be shortdesc.

> "LwDITA compatible documents (MDITA) the first paragraph is treated as
>   a shortdesc element. In generic Markdown documents all paragraphs
>   appear inside the body element."

Here is my executed command.

```
dita --input=sequence.ditamap --format html5
```

And the followings are my sample files.

sequence.ditamap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">

<map>
  <title>Working in the garage</title>
  <topicref href="input.md" format="markdown" />
</map>
```

input.md:

```
# title {.task}

Some Description

1. steps1

    step1 content

2. steps2

    step2 content

This is step result.
```

It will produce index.html and input.html on out directory. I hope the link to input.html on index.html has hover text, but it doesn't.

My expectation is hover text showing "Some Description". What is wrong with me?

I also tried in other cases:

Tri #1 input.md:

```
Some Description(new)

# title {.task}

    Some Description
```

It said `[filter] Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Try #2 sequence.ditamap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE map PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Map//EN" "map.dtd">

<map>
  <title>Working in the garage</title>
  <topicref href="input.md" format="markdown">
    <topicmeta>
        <shortdesc>Some Description(2nd new)</shortdesc>
    </topicmeta>
</topicref>
</map>
```

In this case, there is no error, but these shortdesc description does not appear on output.

Here is a portion of input.html output.

```
<head>
:
:
<meta name="DC.Type" content="task">
<meta name="DC.Format" content="HTML5">
<meta name="DC.Identifier" content="title">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="commonltr.css">
<title>title</title></head>
<body id="title">
:
:
    <h1 class="title topictitle1" id="ariaid-title1">title </h1>
    <div class="body taskbody">
    <section class="section context"></section>
    <ol class="ol steps">
    </ol>
    <section class="section result"></section></div>
:
:
</body>
```

So, how can I enable to generate the shortdesc for HTML5 output? or is it not possible so far?

References:

- [Markdown DITA syntax reference](http://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/markdown-dita-syntax-reference.html) I checked this page for my syntax check.
- [shortdesc](https://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/v1.2/os/spec/langref/shortdesc.html) I also checked this one and tried to write the "shortdesc" on ditamap.
- [Purpose of short descriptions](https://www.oxygenxml.com/dita/styleguide/webhelp-feedback/Artefact/Syntax_and_Markup/c_Purpose_of_Short_Descriptions.html) My expected output is a kind of like this page.
- [Download DITA-OT](http://www.dita-ot.org/download) DITA-OT download link.

Comment: You did not mention what version of the DITA Open Toolkit you are using. Is it DITA OT 3.0.3?

Comment: Yes, DITA OT 3.0.3. Thank you for your comment, I added it.

Comment: I noticed in your example that `<shortdesc>` is in `<topicmeta>`.  Your link to the element on the DITA standards page shows that its usage is expected either here: `topic/shortdesc` or here `topic/abstract/shortdesc`.  In our system, I have seen it as the very next element directly in a concept or task right after the title.  When done this way, it is treated as the first paragraph in content and behaves like shortdesc in processing.  Try editing the xml and see if it has an impact?

Answer (score 1):

Referencing the markdown file like this from the DITA Map:

```
           <topicref href="input.md" format="mdita" />
```

seems to enable that improvement which treats every paragraph as a shortdesc.
But your Markdown file has an attribute which identifies it as a DITA task:

```
  # title {.task}
```

and this no longer properly works with "mdita" format, probably because the LightWeight DITA standard does not offer a possibility to state that a certain Markdown file should be converted to a DITA task.
I'll try to get in touch with Jarno Elovirta who created the Markdown to DITA convertor, see what he has to say about this.

Comment: A draft of the LightWeight DITA standard is available here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/dita/LwDITA/v1.0/cnprd01/LwDITA-v1.0-cnprd01.html

Comment: Thanks again. I found some through your comment. It is still under the draft and DITA-OT is not fully compatible with this standard. That's why 5.4.4 's example will produce the error like  `[filter] Content is not allowed in prolog.`